# Replace outliers by quantiles in R

Tags: r, replace, outliers, quantile

I have been trying to replace outliers 1.5*IQR +/- upper/lower quantile by the upper and lower quantile with the following code:

```
`lower.quantile <- as.numeric(summary(loans$dINC_A)[2])
 lower.quantile
[1] 9000  
upper.quantile <- as.numeric(summary(loans$dINC_A)[5])
> upper.quantile
[1] 21240
IQR <- upper.quantile - lower.quantile
# I replace outliers by the lower/upper bound values
loans$INC_A[ loans$dINC_A < (lower.quantile-1.5*IQR) ] <- lower.quantile
loans$INC_A[ loans$dINC_A > (upper.quantile+1.5*IQR) ] <- upper.quantile`
```

Moreover:

```
> upper.quantile+1.5*IQR
[1] 39600
> lower.quantile-1.5*IQR
[1] -9360
```

However, once I recheck the summary() of my variable, my I get that my maximal value remains 64800>upper.quantile+1.5*IQR=39600

```
> summary(loans$dINC_A)
```

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0    9000   19500   21240   30600   64800

What is missing in my R code ?

Comment: As said, max=64800>upper.quantile+1.5*IQR=39600 remains in the summary, yet I want to replace the value by `loans$INC_A[ loans$dINC_A > (upper.quantile+1.5*IQR) ] <- upper.quantile`

Comment: Reproducible example? [See tips here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: When you replace, you use `loans$INC_A` at the start of the line and `loans$dINC_A` in the middle - then you re-check `loans$dINC_A`. I think the missing `d` in `$INC_A` at the start or your line may be the problem.

Comment: yup that was the problem, thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace outliers with the 5th and 95th percentile values in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339685/how-to-replace-outliers-with-the-5th-and-95th-percentile-values-in-r)

Comment: This is known as winsorization